# Hide one item from input list that is dynamically generated unless other input from list has value in vue / vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So the process is like this. I have a form that is created from api. I want to show all the inputs except for one. That one will only be shown if the user adds value to another specific input from the form.
Something like this is the idea.

```
   <Form>
    <div-for="formItem in state.formItemData">
      <template v-if="formItem.one !== ''">
        <form-input
          v-model="invoiceForm.two"
          :key="formItem.id"
          ref="two"
        ></form-input>
      </template>
    </div>
   </Form>
    
 const invoiceForm = computed({
  get: () => state.forms.formData,
  set: (value) => {
    state.forms.formData= value
  }
})
```

Comment: and what is the problem? just seems strange having so many `<template>`

Comment: @Deniz the first template could be a div. The problem is preventing the input called 'two' from displaying when the form loads. Currently, it loads even with having a v-if or v-show. I only want the input to show if you add a value to input called 'one'

Answer (score 1):

The concept in your problem is very simple, you just must make use of a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that evaluates if there are values in input 1 and it will rerender the component showing input2.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input1: '',
    input2: ''
  },
  methods: {
    verification() {
      console.log(this.input1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    notEmpty() {
      return this.input1 !== '' && this.input1.length > 3;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input @change="verification" type="text" v-model="input1"> <input v-if="notEmpty" type="text" v-model="input2">
</div>
```

Comment: What if we have more than two inputs in the array. I need a way to isolate the input without calling all the inputs separately.

Comment: Your questions is about **That one will only be shown if the user adds value to another specific input from the form**. But the concept is the same. Only evaluate the inputs that you need

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `v-show` if you're eventually going to show/hide it when rendering, especially if it's going to be multiple times. The Vue documentation says that the `v-if` will not be rendered when the initial condition is false.

Source: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show